# Prestashop: error al crear cuenta

Tags: prestashop

Tengo varios problemas con mi tienda online: ilikeverbenas.com

1. No logro crear una cuenta nueva.
2. Con la cuenta que ya tengo creada anteriormente, no me permite crear
   una dirección nueva.
3. Cuando estoy ya logueada, en la página de compra, si intento cambiar
   la dirección me lanza un error de js (que proviene de
   order-address.js):

> TECHNICAL ERROR: unable to save adresses Details: Error thrown:
>   [object Object] Text status: error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagino (espero!) que sea un único problema relacionado con la creación de cuenta/direcciones.

Llevo un par de horas buscando por internet pero no encuentro solución.

Cualquier ayuda sería  muy agradecida!!

**SOLUCIÓN**:

El problema venía de que los formularios de la web redirigían a `http` en lugar de `https`.
Basta ir a:

> Preferencias -> Conficuración, y activar "Enable SSL" y "Enable SSL on
>   all pages"

Comment: Has mirado que te sale en la consola del navegador?

Comment: Me he dado cuenta que el problema 1 y 2 vienen de que no pone el https en los formularios. El problema es que cuando activo el SSL el navegador me dice: The page isn’t redirecting properly. Estoy intentando encontrar solución para esto de activar el SSL, y quiero comprobar que sucede con el problema 3 una vez corregido

Comment: Ve a Preferencias y ahí deselecciona la opción de "Activar SSL en todas las páginas", prueba a ver si con eso te funciona.

Comment: Ha sido fallo mío! En un primer momento acivé SSL, pero no en todas las páginas (estaba convencida de que lo había activado). Gracias Exe!

Comment: Imagino que el 3er error se mantiene, no?

Comment: No. Se ha corregido también. Se daba porque el order-address.js pasa por json el parámetro de la url, y este no tenía el https y daba error. Voy a modificar el post para poner la explicación. Gracias Exe!

Comment: De nada! me alegro que se haya arreglado todo!